# Ruby on Rails 3: In views when to use partial vs helper vs loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, helper, partials

When to choose a partial or helper or a loop in view.
Specifically, when we need a repeated structure only in a single page.
I would like to know which one is a best practice from DRY point of view and Performance point of view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only in a single page, as described, I would consider using a loop or partial.
 - If the output is one or two lines I might just use a loop.
 - If more than that a partial

If used in multiple pages I would use a helper.

**Overall I prefer helpers as they feel like a more object oriented, ruby approach and they are easy and great to have tests for!**

Comment: Probably a loop.  I wouldn't expect much difference and if performance isn't currently an issue I would focus on other factors.  A general rule for performance I have seen is not to address it until you have it.

Comment: @asitmohama For performance of partials vs helper, IIRC both are compiled into executable Ruby code, so there's a minimal difference. What's more to the point, though, is that when performance becomes an issue there are better optimization routes to go down for naïve loops/partials/helpers, like caching, [rendering collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections), etc. Michael's right to focus on whatever is easiest to read and test.